# Routing to/from VPN to WAN

Tags: network, osx-server, vpn, router

I'm running a Mac Mini server, IP 192.168.2.2.  When users connect remotely, often they have issues because their network at home (or wherever) happens to also be 192.168.2.x.  So I instructed server.app to hand out VPN IP's from an unlikely IP range: 192.168.168.x.  Now, that's all working fine, but some users need to send some of their traffic over the VPN, so they have the 'send all traffic over VPN' box checked.  Here's my question: it's not allowing them to get out to the internet, because there's no route between 192.168.168.x and 192.168.2.x.  I've tried everything I can think of to try and make this happen but I'm having no luck.  Help, please?  I need traffic to flow both ways, from WAN to the server to the VPN network to the client and vice versa.

Comment: What is your network mask? Sounds like your server is not in the same network as the VPN IPs?

Comment: @not2savvy yes, exactly. /24

Comment: I think they should be in the same network. Never saw such a configuration like yours.

Comment: @not2savvy you have, actually. Your external (public) IP is a very different network/subnet than your internal, private IP. That works by creating appropriate routes to effectively build a bridge. I've seen, and done, this before; it can work, you just need to know how, and I'm stumped this time for some reason

Comment: You're right, but in this case, you have two local networks. Your router (which I suppose is not your Mac server) must route both of them to the WAN. I'm not sure if all routers will do so. But you might just change your local network mask to /16 on the router to make it work.

Comment: I tried that - no effect :-\

Comment: What is the gateway? 192.168.2.1? And if so, is it this gateway IP configured with the VPN clients?